# How to declare and pass arguments to implicit parameters in Scala 3?

Tags: scala, implicit, dotty, scala-3

I have this code in  scala 2

```
val number = 20

def double(implicit y:Int)={
  y*2
}

def count(implicit x:Int)={
  double
}

object HelloWorld {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    println(count(number)) // res: 40
  }
}
```

Here  `x` parameter of `count` function is annotated as `implicit` so it is able to be passed into the `double` function implicitly. How can I do this in `Scala 3` using given-using / summon?

Comment: `println(count(given number))` if it doesn't work use `using` I haven't learned the syntax yet but the idea is that if you are passing an implicit parameter explicitly you have to make explicit that it was implicit.

Comment: Wait, atter reading the question I am not sure if I understand it right. You want the value `number` to be passed implicitly? you want that to be done using **Scala 3** syntax? You want to know how to pass an implicit _(`given`)_ value explicitly in **Scala 3** as you can in **Scala 2**?

Comment: I want the value I will give in`count` as param, it will also be passed into the `double` function's param implicitly.  In *Scala 2* it is possible. It is very productive to me.

Comment: Yes, you can. The semantics are exactly the same, why don't you just read the docs about given and using and try it? You just need to replace a couple of keywords and that would be.

Comment: Could you change the title to the question to something like "How to declare and pass arguments to implicit parameters in Scala 3", since your question also involves explicitly passing arguments?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The relevant docs section is [Relationship with Scala 2 Implicits - using clauses](https://dotty.epfl.ch/docs/reference/contextual/relationship-implicits.html#using-clauses) which explains

> Explicit arguments to parameters of using clauses must be written
> using `(using ...)`, mirroring the definition syntax.

So definitions

```
def double(using y: Int) = y*2
def count(using x: Int) = double
```

can be applied like so

```
count(using number)
```

Note how conceptually the [same](https://contributors.scala-lang.org/t/dotty-implicit-ly-versus-given-summon/3720/12) keyword `using` is meant to convey both the idea of "requirement" at the definition-site and the idea of "provision" at the call-site.